# Ranking vs Rating

Tags: meaning, difference

I'm really confused about *rating* and *ranking*. 
I found a couple of articles: [this](http://blog.verint.com/ranking-questions-vs-rating-questions) and [this](http://support.turnkeysurveyor.com/entries/20741603-Rating-vs-Ranking-Questions-Pros-and-Cons), which tells basically the same.

What I understood, using my own words, is that *rating* means assign some kind of value to some items (one independent from each other), whilst *ranking* is like sorting, like setting some kind of order among items or comparing them. Am I right? Can you clarify this for me?

I'm asking that because I use to play poker at (¿in?) an on-line site and has *ratings* and *rakings*, which I don't understand.

By the way, I'll be happy if you also tell me any grammatical mistake (or whatever) I made in this post.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I'd say your online poker site would ask you to "rate" a player, and would give *rankings* of multiple players.

Comment: No, as far as I know, it is the site itself who both rate and rank. For rating it uses something called [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) to show how strong a player is. Besides, it also has a ranking based on results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example of both of these terms in cases where they would sound unusual.

> In 'x' exams, he **ranked** 1st out of 40 students *(he "rated" first would sound odd)*.
>
> Critics **rated** the movie 3 stars out of four *(he "ranked" the movie 3 stars out of four would not sound right)*.

The nuance between the two words is that when you 'rank' something, you give it a rank compared to other things in the same set (ranked 1st out of 30 students, or the top-ranked state for auto insurance). It's a comparison among a set of things. First rank, second, third and so on.  Having a "rank" implies there are other things to be ranked against.

However, when you 'rate' something, you may do so by your own standards, but a comparison to other things is not required. As an example, I can "rate" a restaurant's service 3/4 stars, but I don't have to compare it to any other restaurant. I might 'rate' them according to my expertise/experience, but I don't have to have other restaurants to compare them against - my 'rating' is independent of whether or not there's anything else being rated.

My *rank* on ELL is ***third*** worldwide. But, it is not necessary that native speakers ***rate*** me with more stars.

If the sentence looks okay with either of them, it will probably convey the message.  They are very nearly synonyms, and in most cases no one will complain about using one instead of the other.

Comment: Would you “rank” or “rate” something as “above average”?

Answer (score 2):

Rating measures how good something is.

Rank places a number of things in order of how good they are.

Two people can have the same rating, but only one person can have a given rank.

Comment: I don't think any of these statements are exclusive. Rank also measures how good something is. Ratings can also be ordered. And two people can have the same rank. The real difference is what the values are **relative to**. *Rank* is relative to the other people being ranked, and *rating* is relative to a predetermined value scale.